# How do I create an empty tag of anyType without attributes using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, epp

The xsd is here:
http://www.iana.org/assignments/xml-registry/schema/epp-1.0.xsd

I don't want to modify the XSD (maintained by a third party) or the XJC generated classes since they get overwritten with every build.

Here is a sample snippet of the above XSD:

```
<complexType name="dcpAccessType">
    <choice>
        <element name="all"/>
        ...
    </choice>
</complexType>
```

The corresponding XJC generated class looks like this:

```
...
public EppDcpAccessType {
    ...
    public void setAll(Object value) { this.all = value; }
    ...
}
...
```

I want to generate an empty tag such as follows:

```
<all/>
```

But I don't know how to set the property to achieve this.
If I do the following:

```
eppDcpAccessType.setAll("");
```

I get the following (with a bunch of attributes I don't want):

```
<all xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string"></all>
```

If I do the following:

```
eppDcpAccessType.setAll(new Object());
```

I get the following run time error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
```

How do I generate an empty tag without the attributes?

Comment: Why isn't the `all` version with `@xsi:type` not suitable?

Comment: @lexicore I just want a cleaner look... I don't want all those attributes there.

Comment: Are there any technical reasons for this or purely estetical?

Comment: @lexicore aesthetic reasons

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same problem. Third party XSD with a mandatory element without specified type.

I resolved it by using:

`myJaxbType.setTheMandatoryElement(new org.dom4j.dom.DOMElement(""));`

It yielded the outcome:

`<TheMandatoryElement/>`